# Disable access to the Visual Basic editor in Mac Office

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've been working intermittently on an Excel spreadsheet for a customer that does some pretty intense calculations.  We implemented a security procedure using VBA...  At first the requirements were relatively simple, and the overall lack of security in a spreadsheet was discussed and well understood.

Since then the customer has decided that he would like to have the sheet a bit more secure.  Under normal circumstances I would simply disable the developer menu via code.  Unfortunately I just recently found out that the customer, and many of his customers, are using Mac Office.  (There are some customers that are even using 2008 and they found out the hard way that 2008 stopped supporting VBA)

My question is; is it possible to disable access to the Visual Basic editor in Mac Office in versions Pre 2008, and versions 2011 and after since from the research I've done so far points to a return of VBA support in Mac Office in 2011.

Unfortunately I do not have access to a Mac Office version to even really look through the application and or/test different solutions.  In Windows it is possible to right click the VBA project and choose protection from the VBAProject Properties and choose "Lock project for viewing".  Does this option exist and is it effective in Mac Office?

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can lock projects in Mac Office the same way you can in Windows.  Keep in mind that a project that has been locked in one version of Excel cannot be unlocked with a different version.  So, if your customer needs to be able to unlock, they will need to use the same version of Excel you used to lock it.